# How to log in to Facebook automatically via Facebook C# SDK

Tags: c#, wpf, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I try to use Facebook C# SDK to get public account feed **and somehow skip Facebook popup login window stage.**

So when I do this

https://graph.facebook.com/my_user_profile_id/feed?access_token=my_token_I_got_from_FBSDK

It returns the feed of MYAPPLICATION1 (Look at the image below.)

But I want to get a real feed of the account. 
(It is possible to get it via https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer but I have to login!)

So here is my questtion: How do I can get the account feed?

Have I login? If I have how do I can implement it inside of WFP DLL? (I don't use WebBrowser control. No chances to use UI to login.)

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm not sure why it does not work for you, but it worked for me:

1. Go to Graph API Explorer
2. Select your app in the dropdown
3. Click "Get Access Token"
4. Select "read_stream" permission on "Extended Permissions" tab and click "Get token"
5. Open this URL: https://graph.facebook.com/my_user_profile_id/feed?access_token=TOKEN_YOU_GOT_JUST_NOW

I get my feed back.

After that you can extend your token to 60 days as described here (see section 4): https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal

then write it in DB (or hardcode) in your WPF dll.

**UPDATE** - another idea - did you try to get access token for your APP - see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/? If your logic will work with app's access token - then it will be good forever.

Comment: Sorry but I am talking about other thing. I mean I cannot get real account feed under Facebook C# SDK. And to do it I have to popup Facebook dialog window! So I am asking if I can skip this popup and send login/username via HTTPS or somehow and login. This is the problem. In fact I don't need any application feed that we can see under Graph API Explorer. I need access to the "normal" feed without popup login window.

Comment: you can't do that - you can't send login/password to FB server because you are not allowed to proxy them as per FB policy: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/ - section II, item 2